# What should be the data type for the hashed value of a password encrypted using PBKDF2?

Tags: hash, encoding, plsql, sqldatatypes, pbkdf2

I am trying to learn to use PBKDF2 hash functions for storing passwords in the database. I have a rough draft of the procedure that I'll be using to generate the hashed function. But while I am creating the table in PL/SQL Developer which will hold the generated hashed password, what should I declare the data type for the encrypted password variable?

It might be a lame question but I'm trying to learn online. It would be a huge help if I can get links for further study as well. thank you. please help

Answer (score 1):

The first link, as always, is [Thomas Pornin's canonical answer to How to securely hash passwords](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31846/39623).

---

## Storage in the database

- The hash can be stored in BINARY format for the least transformations and smallest number of bytes; see below for sizes.

  - Alternately, store it in a CHAR after converting to hex, which costs a transformation and double the bytes of the BINARY size
  - Alternatively, store it in a CHAR after converting to Base64, which costs a transformation and 4/3rds the number of bytes of BINARY size plus padding
  - i.e. PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-512 where all 64 bytes of output are used would be

    - BINARY(64) as binary
    - CHAR(128) as hex
    - CHAR(88) as Base64
- The number of iterations should be stored in an INT, so it can be trivially increased later
- The salt, which must be a per-user, cryptographically random value, can be stored in a BINARY format for the smallest number of bytes, and should be at least 12, and preferably 16-24 bytes long.

  - i.e. for a 16 byte binary salt

    - BINARY(16) as binary
    - CHAR(32) as hex
    - CHAR(24) as Base64
- Optionally a password hash algorithm version as a small INT type

  - i.e. 1 for PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-512, and then later if you change to BCrypt, 2 for BCrypt, etc.

---

## Normal PBKDF2 considerations

- Consider using PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-512, as SHA-512 in particular has 64-bit operations that reduce the advantage most GPU based attackers have over you as of early 2016.
- Use a high (hundreds of thousands or high tens of thousands) of iterations.
- Don't ask for a larger number of PBKDF2 output bytes than the native hash function supports

  - SHA-512 <= 64 bytes
  - SHA-384 <= 48 bytes
  - SHA-256 <= 32 bytes
  - SHA-224 <= 28 bytes
  - MD5 <= 20 bytes

Comment: @MaahiChatterjee - if you like it, upvote.  I hope it helps you be more secure!